# iMessage extension in swift

Tags: ios, swift, imessage-extension

I want to make an iMessage app extension for my app, once I have it set up how do I use code from the actual app in the extension? Do I need to import certain files from my app?

I have App Groups set up for both Main app and iMessage extension, how can I access classes from the main app?

Comment: Any Swift files that you want to use in your extension and your app have to be added to both targets.

Comment: how would one do that @jnpdx

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have any source files you want included in the extension added to the extension target (as well as the app target, if they're shared).

One way to do this:

1. Go to the View menu in Xcode and select Inspectors -> File.
2. Navigate to whichever file you want to add to the extension, and then in the File Inspector (which should be visible in the right-hand sidebar), make sure the target for your extension is selected under "Target Membership"

[image]

Comment: @ShedSports did this answer your question? If so, you can mark it as accepted with the green checkmark.